# InvalidOperationException when reparenting WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program that does the following:

- Create a WPF control
- User reparenting to show the control inside another window (Notepad)
- Add a WindowsFormsHost to the control

The code is

```
UserControl1 control = new UserControl1();
control.AddFormsHostWithDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));;
if (this.TryGetHandleFromName("Notepad", out IntPtr handle))
{
   HwndSourceParameters pa = new HwndSourceParameters("WPF Source", 400, 300);
   pa.ParentWindow = handle;
   pa.WindowStyle = 0x40000000 | 0x10000000; // child and visible
   pa.UsesPerPixelOpacity = false;
   pa.SetPosition(5, 5);
   HwndSource src = new HwndSource(pa);
   src.RootVisual = control;
}
```

That code worked for years, but since Windows10 CreatorsUpdate, it crashes as soon as the WindowsFormsHost is added. The message and stack trace is

```
'CreatorsUpdateCrashDemo.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: 
CreatorsUpdateCrashDemo.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Hosted HWND must be a child window of the specified parent.
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildWindow(HandleRef hwndParent)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildOrReparentWindow()
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.OnSourceChanged(Object sender, SourceChangedEventArgs e)
```

Full demo can be found at http://www.seetec.eu/entwicklung/BRAU/CreatorsUpdateCrash.zip

How to reproduce:

- Use Windows10 CreatorsUpdate
- Download demo
- start notepad
- start CreatorsUpdateCrashDemo
- Click the crash button
- Application crashes after 2 seconds

Does anybody know what to change to avoid this crash? Adding the FormsHost before doing the reparenting resolves the issue but is not possible in the real application.

Additional Information:

The problem is clearly in WindowsFormsHost. Something inside the BuildWindowCore method changed with CreatorsUpdate. After the call to BuildWindowCore in HwndHost.BuildWindow there are some checks, and one of them fails. Speficially it is this code in HwndHost:

```
// Make sure the child window is the child of the expected parent window.
if(hwndParent.Handle != UnsafeNativeMethods.GetParent(_hwnd))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.ChildWindowMustHaveCorrectParent));
}
```

More additional information: I found out that setting "Override high dpi scaling behavior" in the properties of the executable resolves the problem. That may be a workaround, but I still would like to understand what is going on. Is what I'm doing simply not supported? Is there a better way to do it?

[image: Screenshot of application's properties dialog]

Answer (score 0):

Update .Net Framework on your machine and solution and don't forgett NuGet update.

Comment: Update to what? I'm using .Net 4.6.2 and the application doesn't use any NuGet packages, just the .Net framework.